# Laravel Trailing Slashes redirect to url with public

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

In a project i'm developing with Laravel, i have a strange problem.

If i try to go to url http://localhost/admin/page, laravel correct redirect me to http://localhost/admin/page, but if i try to go to http://localhost/admin/page/, with trailing slash, i'm redirected to  http://localhost/public/admin/page.

This is my .htaccess on the root of project:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

And this is my .htaccess on public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

</IfModule>
```

I would like to redirect to http://localhost/admin/page even if i go to http://localhost/admin/page/. How could i solve?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after some debug i have discover that actual configuration already works fine. Problem was with Google Chrome Cache. For future reference, simply use my configuration, clear browser cache and try again.